# Should the update for my app be compatible with iPhone 5 screen?

Tags: iphone, app-store, ios6, appstore-approval

I had some minor changes to an older app of mine. Now, I am going to update a newer version on the App Store. But it doesn't have support for iOS 6 or iPhone 5 screen.

I understand, I will have to give support for iOS 6. But should I update the App for iPhone 5 screen too? I don't consider supporting iPhone 5 screen right now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It isn't obligatory for app to support new futures of iOS6 like so-called 'GiraffeMode' of iPhone5.